# Create a simple customer blacklist Woocommerce plugin

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to make a simple custom plugin for Woocommerce that will allow me to set specific clients to a "blacklist".
Basically, the plugin creates a menu "Blacklist Checker" in the admin dashboard where I have two fields with an e-mail address and phone number. When the client place an order using the e-mail address and phone number that is saved in the blacklist the plugin check and will display a notice in the backend Order details page.

The problem is that the notice does not appear on the backend Order detail page. What I'm doing wrong?
Thank you!

This is the current code I have:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Blacklist Checker
Description: A simple WooCommerce plugin to manage a blacklist of clients.
Version: 1.1
Author: Razvan
*/

// Create the blacklist menu in the admin dashboard
function blacklist_checker_menu() {
    add_menu_page('Blacklist Checker', 'Blacklist Checker', 'manage_options', 'blacklist-checker', 'blacklist_checker_page');
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'blacklist_checker_menu');

// Create the content for the blacklist menu page
function blacklist_checker_page() {
    if (isset($_POST['add_to_blacklist'])) {
        $email = sanitize_email($_POST['email']);
        $phone = sanitize_text_field($_POST['phone']);

        // Add to the blacklist option in the WordPress options table
        $blacklist = get_option('blacklist_checker_blacklist', array());
        $blacklist[] = array('email' => $email, 'phone' => $phone);
        update_option('blacklist_checker_blacklist', $blacklist);
    }

    if (isset($_POST['remove_from_blacklist'])) {
        $email = sanitize_email($_POST['remove_email']);
        $phone = sanitize_text_field($_POST['remove_phone']);

        // Remove from the blacklist option in the WordPress options table
        $blacklist = get_option('blacklist_checker_blacklist', array());
        $updated_blacklist = array();

        foreach ($blacklist as $entry) {
            if ($entry['email'] !== $email || $entry['phone'] !== $phone) {
                $updated_blacklist[] = $entry;
            }
        }

        update_option('blacklist_checker_blacklist', $updated_blacklist);
    }

    $blacklist = get_option('blacklist_checker_blacklist', array());
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <h2>Blacklist Checker</h2>

        <h3>Add to Blacklist</h3>
        <form method="post" action="">
            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" required>
            <label for="phone">Phone Number:</label>
            <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" required>
            <input type="submit" name="add_to_blacklist" class="button button-primary" value="Add to Blacklist">
        </form>

        <h3>Blacklisted Clients</h3>
        <ul>
            <?php foreach ($blacklist as $entry) : ?>
                <li>
                    Email: <?php echo esc_html($entry['email']); ?>,
                    Phone: <?php echo esc_html($entry['phone']); ?>
                    <form method="post" action="">
                        <input type="hidden" name="remove_email" value="<?php echo esc_attr($entry['email']); ?>">
                        <input type="hidden" name="remove_phone" value="<?php echo esc_attr($entry['phone']); ?>">
                        <input type="submit" name="remove_from_blacklist" class="button" value="Remove">
                    </form>
                </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <?php
}

// Check if a client is in the blacklist when a new order is placed
function check_blacklist_on_order($order_id) {
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
    $customer_email = $order->get_billing_email();
    $customer_phone = $order->get_billing_phone();

    // Get the blacklist from the WordPress options table
    $blacklist = get_option('blacklist_checker_blacklist', array());

    // Check if email or phone number is in the blacklist
    foreach ($blacklist as $entry) {
        if ($entry['email'] == $customer_email || $entry['phone'] == $customer_phone) {
            add_action('admin_notices', 'blacklist_notice');
            break;
        }
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_new_order', 'check_blacklist_on_order');

// Display a red notice in the backend order edit page
function blacklist_notice() {
    global $post;

    $order_id = $post->ID;
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
    $customer_email = $order->get_billing_email();
    $customer_phone = $order->get_billing_phone();

    // Get the blacklist from the WordPress options table
    $blacklist = get_option('blacklist_checker_blacklist', array());

    // Check if email or phone number is in the blacklist
    foreach ($blacklist as $entry) {
        if ($entry['email'] == $customer_email || $entry['phone'] == $customer_phone) {
            echo '<div class="error"><p>This customer is on the blacklist. Exercise caution!</p></div>';
            break;
        }
    }
}
```